# Can't compile assets with Gulp

Tags: gulp, octobercms, laravel-elixir

Every tutorial or doc I find says that I should do something like this:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir.config.assetsPath = 'themes/ei/assets/src';
elixir.config.publicPath = 'themes/ei/assets/'

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('style.scss');
    mix.scripts('main.js');
});
```

But when I run `gulp` from the command line I get:

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (/home/andrew/Development/eiweb/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:10:3)
at Gulp.task (/home/andrew/Development/eiweb/node_modules/undertaker/lib/task.js:13:8)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/andrew/Development/eiweb/node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/tasks/recipes/default.js:30:6)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
at requireDir (/home/andrew/Development/eiweb/node_modules/require-dir/index.js:123:33)
```

My `package.json` file includes:

```
"dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-18"
}
```

...and I have `gulp-cli` installed global.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurs because of version issue `gulp 4` has different signature for the `task` and `laravel-elixir` uses old signature of `gulp 3` so it will cause error.

**Best case would be to move** https://laravel-mix.com as its based on `webpack` so it support more functionalities. also `laravel-mix` syntax is similar so its plus point.

> **For laravel-mix** create this pacjage `package.json` file in root. or user latest from [ https://github.com/laravel/laravel ] public repo.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```

> Create `webpack.mix.js` in your root

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

// change theme path according to your need.    
const themePath = 'themes/rainlab-bonjour'; 

mix.options({
  publicPath: themePath + '/assets/compiled/'
})

// change script name and path according to your need.
mix.js(themePath + '/assets/src/main.js', 'main.js')
   .sass(themePath + '/assets/src/main.scss', 'main.css');
```

> Commands [ you can use this command with yarn or npm (I am using yarn)], you can read more info here. [ https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/workflow ]
>
> **yarn watch** -> it will watch files and compile files then generate compiled out-put in `publicPath` directory. in our case files will be.

```
themes/rainlab-bonjour/assets/compiled/main.js
themes/rainlab-bonjour/assets/compiled/main.css
```

> Now you can just include them in theme using `'assets/compiled/main.js'|theme` OctoberCms filter.

if you have any doubts please comment.

Comment: The documentation for this solution can be found on https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/installation