# Laravel - Why cannot find asset from gulp laravel

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, file-not-found, laravel-elixir

[image: This structure folder and gupl]

[image: this error not foud]

please help me, why cant find asset from gulp laravel ?

Comment: You follow this link.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56030750/cant-compile-assets-with-gulp . may be same problem . or read the documentation for this solution can be found on https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/installation